# Should good duplicates be up voted - then closed?

Tags: discussion

Plenty of questions are duplicates of others, for instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596762/how-do-i-check-out-just-one-file-from-a-remote-repository-in-git
[How to checkout only one file from git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository)

The questions seem wellformed and articulated in my eyes, but the first is a duplicate of the second. Should I just vote to close it or should I up vote it, and then vote to close it (seems friendlier :-) )?

In the case that the newer question is "better" than the one it is duplicate of should the old question be updated?

Comment: How hard was it to find the duplicate question ? If very easy, that means lack of research effort and deserves, while not downvote (if everything else in the question is correct), no upvote either. But in the end, the votes are yours so do as you wish.

Comment: What is really needed is some kind of new SO/SE functionality that: 1) drives users to the good questions with good answers that are similar to theirs, and 2) gets in the way (nicely) when a user is about to ask a duplicative question.  I don't have any real solutions or improvements or I would suggest them.  Lately, I have been thinking that SO/SE could pre-categorize questions and answers into basic, intermediate, and advanced based primarily on the "status" of the asker (in other words, it is unlikely that people with significant status points would ask basic questions).

Comment: In this particular case it was very easy for *ME* to find the answer, but for someone not even remotely familiar with git it might be harder. As for automatically categorising questions into basic, intermediate and advanced it seem like it would stratify the community. Also if I started asking questions about RPG programming I think my questions wouldn't  be intermediate just bc I have some rep on SO. Sure you could refine it by subdividing rep onto labels,  but what would the point be? Wouldn't it just strangle newcomers?

Comment: Those types of questions are really great to have on this site. When another beginner goes to Google a question using their still limited vocabulary, those duplicates questions are the ones they will find first.

Comment: I would first vote to close it. Then, if the answer could *easily* have been found by searching then I would downvote it too. As for the old question, I would locate the most "generic" question instead or most voted/oldest and mark as duplicate.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with upvoting (or at least not downvoting) good duplicate questions. I don't think your example is a good duplicate question, though; it's a good question (if it wasn't a duplicate), but it does nothing useful as a duplicate. All of the search keywords in those two question titles are the same, which suggests a lack of research effort worthy of a downvote and also means that it's not going to make the information any easier to find.

Comment: Duplicate questions aren't always bad.  I hate it when a question is asked clearly and concisely, receives clear and concise answers as a result, and then someone comes along and closes the new (better) question as a duplicate of an old question that is sloppily worded and has confusing or bad answers.  What needs to happen in that case is for the old question to be closed as a duplicate of the new one, and the new one left open - but I've never seen that happen.

Comment: @JeffLoughlin  If you see a sloppily worded question, FIX IT.

Comment: **there is no such thing as a good duplicate**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/deliberately-opening-duplicate-questions-as-search-targets

Comment: **Another thing to consider**: When searching for an answer relating to a topic on which you are a novice, sometimes (even after researching) there's a crucial detail that was overlooked, and your posted question ends up actually being a duplicate. Those who vote to close the question generally link to the original question, so this is not a problem, unless (as others have stated above) the new question and answers contain more useful content than the old.

Answer (score 13):

I think some duplicates can be upvoted, or at least it's not always good to downvote.

First I noticed that for many searches in google, duplicate questions show up instead of the first asked questions.

Also I was recently searching a way to print grayscale PDFs with another color. I couldn't find any answers. So I asked here:
https://superuser.com/questions/874525/how-to-print-a-black-grayscale-pdf-in-some-chosen-color

Then later searching for longer, I found another question with an answer to mine but the other question was much more specific and one couldn't easily find unless he wants exactly the same:
https://superuser.com/questions/202935/how-can-i-print-out-a-pdf-substituting-pixels-for-blue-pixels

So I was asking how to change color of PDF, the other is asking how to print in blue. I could have removed my question but decided to leave it so somebody else can find the link in my question to the other question.

Still I got 2 downvotes with no explanation... oh poor me! what an injustice, how can I continue with my life after this?! :)

Comment: If you keeping the question and since you already have answer for your question, why not to post it there then? It would save someone time jumping to blue pixel question.

Comment: @SebastianK, that's a good point and I can do it, but in this case am I claiming the reputation that somebody else deserves? If user does not go to the actual answer, then the original author cannot get any reputation. I thought my course of action is politically correct :)

Comment: @akostadinov I like your course of action. You actually help people find the other answer. I always appreciate answers to duplicates or similar questions that leave links to more specific answers that I probably would have not found otherwise. Upvote for your answer and behavior.

Comment: @akostadinov - I see - makes sense. I suppose one thing that may be bit confusing is that this question would appear as unanswered, but when people arrive there to answer it, they will see it does not require any.

Answer (score 7):

If you see a good question, go ahead and upvote it. The last thing we want to do is drive away the people who know how to ask a good question! With a little encouragement, they might come back and ask a question that is *not* a duplicate.

I think the drive to determine a canonical question that all others are a duplicate of is slightly misguided. Consider all the different criteria that you might use to determine which is the master:

- The earliest question.
- The first duplicate you found.
- The question you remember answering in the past.
- The highest-voted question.
- The question with the subjective best wording.
- The question that comes first in a Google search.
- The question with the highest-voted answer.
- The question with the subjective most complete answer.

I've seen plenty of examples where you might argue that the wrong choice was made.

Comment: You want to choose whatever question is going to be most valuable for other people with the problem to find.  Many of these points will influence one's decision on which would be most useful, but all of these are imperfect metrics to come to that decision.  Note that anytime two duplicate questions both have very useful content, they can always be merged.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the guidance in the voting-tooltips:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.
>
> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

1. So, can you find a duplicate by searching for (part of) the title, or a snippet from the body?

   If yes, downvote.
2. Is the question clear and could conceivably be useful?

   Consider upvoting.

Aside from that, close it as a duplicate if it is a duplicate.

If you think the answers on the duplicate aren't exhaustive yet, you are welcome to add the missing information in your own answer, or if too little for that as a comment.

And you can decide that the new question is actually better as the master.
In that case, you should probably also flag the old one for merging.