# I found an answer but the question was very different from mine. How can I make the answer easier to find for other people?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

I almost always find an answer to a question I have on the internet. Often though the context where the answer is presented is very different from the question I initially had.

Many questions also contain long snippets of code and the answer only relates how to solve the problem in the OP's code. The problem and answer could often be purified down to answer a much general set of problems so that less effort would be needed from other people to use the Q&A. How can I use Stack Overflow to provide more usable Q&A for people who use the Internet?

Is it possible to somehow clarify the already existing Q&A? Is it possible to create new better Q&A that might get most of its contents from already existing Q&A on this and other sites?

Comment: Hmm, make your question as generic as possible? Dupe answers don't rely on the specific question context that much.

Comment: "to answer a much general set of problems so that less effort would be needed from other people to use the Q&A." Could you post some examples of what you're talking about please.

Comment: Related: [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307615)

Comment: @JoshCaswell the fact that it is an excellent dupe asking about purposely writing a dupe, posted as a related question to this question about possibly writing a dupe... inception.

Answer (score 21):

A lot of Q&A on SO and the rest of the internet are very restricted to a specific problem, so if you are able to broaden the Q&A so that it can be found easier and it helps more people, **then yes please do!**

It might be closed as a duplicate, but there is nothing wrong with posting duplicate questions, because they enhance the chance it can be found, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/deliberately-opening-duplicate-questions-as-search-targets) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate)

There is also no objection to use other content provided you give credit to the source.  [[When is using an other poster's content plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism]))

Comment: I would contend that if the question is sufficiently more generic, and the answer more widely applicable, then the *older* question should be closed :)

Comment: anonymous users don't see duplicates: they are redirected automatically. If you want to close something as a duplicate; make sure that the answer works for all questions

Comment: @MatthieuM. Strongly agree, I hate it when a well written, clear, simplified, question is duped to an awful mess of nonsense which though answered, contains a load of other mess from the OP's specific problem. Non-logged-in users (at least) are automatically redirected so they never get to see the good question/answer.