# Ask a question whose duplicate exists but is low quality

Tags: discussion

I've hypothetically identified a low quality question with an acceptable but not accepted answer. It has been established that one could re-ask a question and immediately close it as duplicate:

- [*Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate)
- [*Deliberately opening duplicate questions as search targets*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/deliberately-opening-duplicate-questions-as-search-targets)

But in this case, should someone ask and answer a question as thoroughly as possible and vote to close the *other* question as duplicate of the new one?

If not, what should one do?

Comment: Like [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272537/closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-an-off-topic-question) on [meta.se] talking about?

Comment: Could you just edit the existing question and post your answer there?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't link a lousy Q+A as a duplicate.  Do it the other way around.

Comment: @HansPassant Well he's saying the question isn't great, but the answer is fine, so that's a lot less of a problem.