# Extensively edit a question so as to have a clean target for duplicates

Tags: discussion, support

I found a question that is likely to be a frequently-asked question, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992569/aws-cloudformation-command-fails-on-aws-example-templates) one.

The answer there answers a question many will have, on the meaning of a confusing AWS CloudFormation error message.

At the moment, this Q&A is hard to find. When searching for the key phrases on Google, Stack Overflow is outranked by a number of other hits, like answers buried in comments at GitHub etc.

My hope is that when someone types the search phrase into Google, "*aws cloudformation template format error unsupported structure*", they should find that question and its answer. It will be better still if they find a clearly-worded question there, and know immediately that they are in the right place.

So, can I edit that question extensively, remove all the extraneous text, change the title, and make it clearly ask the right question? If not, what else can I do?

See also:

- [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314716/ask-a-question-whose-duplicate-exists-but-is-low-quality) related unanswered question, which could also do with an answer.

Comment: If it is outranked by a number of other sites, either SO's SEO is badly screwed, or the others are doing a much better job!

Comment: Not that I know much about SEO but I assume it is outranked as a result of other posts (e.g. AWS developer forums) mentioning the key phrase in the title, and this question going with "AWS cloudformation command fails on AWS example templates".

Comment: That is part of on-page SEO. But yeah, I get what you mean.

Comment: That question is kindasorta off topic, tho. Be more on topic at SF.

Comment: Questions about tools used by developers are not off-topic.

Comment: Additionally, AWS CloudFormation is a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and is as much programming as YAML, HTML etc etc so, as a .NET developer wading in outside your area of expertise, would you be so kind as to retract the close vote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't receive any answers here, but quite a few upvotes, which I interpret as suggesting this is fine. I'm marking this as the accepted answer.