# What is the correct action when I see that I have made a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I ask questions and then later see that another earlier question has already provided the answer. If there is no answer or additional helpful information on my question I will often delete it to prevent leaving a duplicate lying around or requiring votes to close just to close it (not trying to avoid close votes here or the like, just to remove the process to get to the correct end result quicker).

Is this the correct action? Or should I vote to close and wait for enough others to also do so?

To clarify, this is a case where *I* find the question that my own is duplicating, not where it is suggested by comment or close vote... though I guess those cases may match if someone votes to close with a question that I agree makes mine a duplication.

Here is a recent (deleted) example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348685/how-to-restrict-focus-to-complete-row-only-on-datagridview

Comment: Why are you only finding the duplicates *after* you've posted?

Comment: Related: [Deliberately opening duplicate questions as search targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290768)

Comment: Same standards apply here as everywhere else. If you think your question is *useful*, then you should keep it. If not, you should clean up after yourself and delete it, saving others the trouble. So the only issue is what constitutes "useful" for a duplicate? The answer is, does your question provide an alternative path to find the other question? If you were unable to find it after doing a search, it's probably the case that the master question isn't appearing in search queries for common terms, which would mean that your duplicate is actually adding value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I sometimes find that questions that show up in "Related" beside the published question did not show up in my initial search or in the "Questions that may already have your answer". I do generally search in both google and SO with a numerous amount of search terms before posting, but continue to do so (if I have time available) with more and more search terms after I've posted and so sometimes find more that way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be looking for duplicates before you even post the question.

That said if you tried, didn't find anything, posted the question and then you come to find a duplicate you have a couple choices.  If you feel your question would be a useful signpost to help others find the answer then you can self close as a duplicate (as long as you have at least 250 rep).  Making the answer easier to find is a good thing.  There is no problem having good duplicates.

If you don't feel like it will be useful at all then you can delete it like you do now.  It doesn't hurt anything to remove something that isn't useful.