# Is there/should there be a feature to alias/suggest duplication without making a full question post?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search

Sometimes I'll want to ask a question and then only after some digging realize there is another question that mine would be a duplicate of at which point I don't ask the question.

However, if I had asked the question and then marked my own question as a duplicate of the other question, I could save anyone who asked the question the way I did some work.

But I have never, and wouldn't be likely to ask a question that I already know there's a duplicate of.

So: is there/ should there be a feature where a title alias can be marked for a question such that future seekers find it more easily.

Alternatively a feature wherein the question body explicitly acknowledges the relation to the duplicate, and redirects to the duplicate without the stigma and downvotes of current duplicate culture.

Comment: Sort of related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290768/1197934

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we need this feature. Ideally, people will do what you did, but if you really want to save them some work, consider one of two remaining options:

- Post the question anyway, and then vote to close it as a duplicate of the desired target, because the point of the duplicate close reason/feature is to act as a signpost, which has value in pointing users to the right method. I think the duplicate signpost implementation works pretty well, especially now that we can edit questions to link to multiple duplicate targets.

Or, preferably:

- You have the edit privilege, so you can edit the question you found, if possible, so that its title or body reflects a slightly more generic or searchable version or format of the question or problem (**without** changing the gist of the question/problem or invalidating any existing answers, of course).