# Should I create signpost (duplicate) questions on purpose?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, signpost-questions

I was just looking for an answer to a question and did not find it. Therefore, I was about to post my own question. But after a lot more digging, I finally found the answer on SO.

Should I now post my question with my own keywords anyway and immediately mark it as a duplicate or is that *unwanted* on SO?

Just to be clear, I do not want to post my own Q&A, but just the question as a signpost.

Comment: @cigien that seems to be more about creating listing questions, this seems to be simply about creating a signpost as a duplicate for a single question.

Comment: No, you should not intentionally create duplicate questions in order to act as signposts. People are very bad at predicting what will be a useful signpost. (A problem we see over and over when people want to delete duplicate questions because they predict that they won't be good signposts.) You may, however, find it appropriate to edit the title and/or body of the question that you found in order to make it findable using the keyword(s) that you originally used in an attempt to find it.

Comment: This makes me think, are questions rapidly closed as duplicates also worth keeping as signposts? It seems that [search engines are also redirected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr#comment346409_125807) from duplicate questions (We all know SE's search is not that great). Don't know if this is still the implementation.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is a pretty unreliable statistic I would say. It might just be that a gold badger happened to land their eyes on it and hit the close hammer based on a list of bookmarks they keep. I would rather just look at the quality of the post itself to make any judgements about whether something should stay or not.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm a little confused now. The dupe targets suggest that it actually *would* be a good idea to create signposts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307617/11942268

Comment: @Gimby what I mean is the reason we keep duplicates is that they present the same problem in a different way improving searchability. If search engines are redirected from the duplicate they won't get the chance to index the duplicate, hence actually not helping in searchability.

Comment: Read the answers to [the primary question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290768), please.